# synchronized method issue in java

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

I have three different synchronized methods show below.

A:

```
 public synchronized static int addCount1() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
            count++;
        }
        return count;
    }
```

B:

```
static void addCount2() {
    synchronized (TestDoubleThread.class) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
            count++;
        }
    }
}
```

C:

```
void addCount3(String key) {
    synchronized (myMap.get(key)) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
            count++;
        }
    }
}
```

All of them can do synchronize as I expect. However, I want to know which one is better, and what is the significant different between all of them. Especially for the case B and case C.

Here is my complete code:

```
public class TestDoubleThread extends Thread {

    String jobNmae;

    static int count = 0;

    TestDoubleThread(String jobName) {
        this.jobNmae = jobName;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        TestDoubleThread t1 = new TestDoubleThread("A");
        TestDoubleThread t2 = new TestDoubleThread("B");
        t1.start();
        t2.start();

        Thread.sleep(3 * 1000L);
        System.out.println("count=" + TestDoubleThread.count);
    }

    public void run() {
        // addCount2();
        addCount3("A");
    }

    public synchronized static int addCount1() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
            count++;
        }
        return count;
    }

    static void addCount2() {
        synchronized (TestDoubleThread.class) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
                count++;
            }
        }
    }

    void addCount3(String key) {
        synchronized (myMap.get(key)) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
                count++;
            }
        }
    }

    public static java.util.Map<String, TestDoubleThread> myMap = new java.util.HashMap<String, TestDoubleThread>();
    static {
        myMap.put("A", new TestDoubleThread("A"));
        myMap.put("B", new TestDoubleThread("B"));
    }
}
```

Comment: `A` and `B` synchronize on the class itself, `C` synchronizes on a lock object that has nothing to do with the static counter that is supposedly being protected. So `C` is probably broken.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`addCount2` is synchronized on `TestDoubleThread.class` while `addCount3` is synchronized on the `TestDoubleThread` instance returned by `myMap.get(key)`. Since you execute it with `addCount3("A");`, both threads are synchronized on the same object, so one has to wait before the other can execute the method. Therefore it will behave exactly as `addCount2`, which also synchronizes on the same object.

If, on the other hand, you change it to `addCount3(this.jobNmae)`, each thread would be synchronized on a different object, so both threads will be able to execute `addCount3` at the same time, and your `count` will get screwed.

Comment: and if you call `addCount("C")` you'll get a NullPointerException.